# Count and randomly display image from given directory

Tags: c#, image, directory

I have C# handler file that is passed a path(a local directory). This path sometimes contains one image, sometimes 100's.  The purpose of the handler is to randomly pick one of the images, and return it to the slideshow.aspx file which called the handler. This is all working find except in some cases I am getting '500' errors and the following stack trace in instances where only ONE image exists - and sometimes, not all:

```
[ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename) +685715
SafetyMonitors.GetImage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +213
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +913
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

Here is my handler code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace SafetyMonitors
{
/// <summary>
/// Grab images in shared public directory, based on incoming querystring path variable. randomize. stream new image back to request.
/// </summary>
public class GetImageUpdated : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var SharePath = context.Request["SharePath"];
        Random rnd = new Random(); //randomize image
        string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\inetpub\wwwroot\service center monitors\Shares\" + SharePath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        if(images.Length == 1)
        {
            string imgToDisplay = images[images.Length];
            Image img = new Bitmap(imgToDisplay);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string imgToDisplay = images[rnd.Next(images.Length - 1)];
            Image img = new Bitmap(imgToDisplay);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
            }
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried adding in that IF statement to handle the case for only 1 image in the directory, thinking it must be something to do with the counting and random().

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Weird, if you have just one image this code should give you an Index Out of range exception. Try to use _string imgToDisplay = images[images.Length-1];_ also your if condition doesn't handle correctly if you don't have any image at all. Are you sure that there are only images in that folder?

Comment: Tried that as well, same result. Oddly enough if I hardcode string imgToDisplay = images[0]; I am still getting the same result... 50% of the time the image, the other half '500' errors.  And yes, just one image in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
   if(images.Length == 1)
    {
        string imgToDisplay = images[images.Length];
        Image img = new Bitmap(imgToDisplay);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }
```

is looking for a value in the second storage location of the array... remember they're zero based.

You should use:

```
string imgToDisplay = images[images.Length-1];
```

Comment: Good catch, sadly even with the above change I still receive the same result.